# Break and goto placement inside a nested switch

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include "Menu.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>


void Menu::displayMenu() {
    cout << " 1. New User login \n 2. View available vehicles \n 3. Return Vehicle \n 4. Exit Program \n";

    char choice;
    cin >> choice;

main:
    switch (choice) {
    case '1': //new user option
        login();
        break;


    case '2': //This will be the option for viewing available cars. each choice in this switch will lead to car info and choice to rent.

    carmenu:
        cout << "Now viewing available vehicles...Select vehicle for further information...\n";
        cout << " 1. Toyota Carolla \n 2. Toyota Rav4 \n 3. Toyota Prius \n 4. Ford Mustang \n 5. Ford Transit \n 6. Main Menu \n";
        char rent;
        char carchoice;
        cin >> carchoice;
        switch (carchoice) {
        case '1':
            cout << "Toyota Carolla..\n Passenger class \n 30 MPG \n 4 Doors \n";
            cout << "Enter Y to rent vehicle or enter N to return to car selection...\n";
            cin >> rent;
            if (rent == 'Y') {
                //construct

            }
            else if (rent == 'N') { goto carmenu; };

        case '2':
            cout << "Toyota Rav4..\n Passenger class \n 24 MPG \n 5 Doors \n";
            cout << "Enter Y to rent vehicle or enter N to return to car selection...\n";
            cin >> rent;
            if (rent == 'Y') {
                //call passenger car constructor called Rav4 with proper data entries.

            }
            else if (rent == 'N') { goto carmenu; };
            break;

        case '3':
            cout << "Toyota Prius.. \n Passenger class \n 54 MPG \n 4 Doors \n";
            cout << "Enter Y to rent vehicle or enter N to return to car selection...\n";
            cin >> rent;
            if (rent == 'Y') {
                //call passenger car constructor called Prius with proper data entries.

            }
            else if (rent == 'N') { goto carmenu; };
            break;

        case '4':
            cout << "Ford Mustang.. \n Passenger class \n 18 MPG \n 2 Doors \n";
            cout << "Enter Y to rent vehicle or enter N to return to car selection...\n";
            cin >> rent;
            if (rent == 'Y') {
                //call passenger car constructor called Mustang with proper data entries.
                break;
            }
            else if (rent == 'N') { goto carmenu; };
            break;

        case '5':
            cout << "Ford Transit ..\n Cargo class \n 14 MPG \n";
            cout << "Enter Y to rent vehicle or enter N to return to car selection...\n";
            cin >> rent;
            if (rent == 'Y') {
                Cargo van(14);
                van.set_purpose();

            }

            else if (rent == 'N') { goto carmenu; };

        case '6':
            goto main;


        }//second switch

    }//first switch
}//function end
```

I hope this isn't too difficult to read...I am doing a project in which I have to design a car rental program for a company. The second case of the main menu takes the user to a menu in which he can select what type of car to rent. The menu isn't completely finished but I have completed the class for option 5 of the car selection menu. When the car is rented (Y is entered for the if statement) the constructor for cargo is called properly but the program either ends right after the purpose is input OR it returns to the car rental page. I don't know where to put my breaks or go to statements. Can anyone help??

Comment: split in sub functions, and you won't need `goto`.

Comment: *I hope this isn't too difficult to read..*  -- It is -- you're using `goto`.  No one wants to read potential [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

Answer (score 0):

By putting `break` at the end of each of your cases it will break out of the cases below the current case and execute the rest of the code.  If you input 'Y' for your rent choice, your program will return to the car menu again because the variable `choice` is never reassigned so it will remain '2'.  If you input 'N', you will return to selecting a car because of your `goto carmenu`.  For all other inputs, you do not have an else case so the program will simply exit after the break.

I would suggest breaking up your code into functions instead of using `goto`.  It will become much easier to follow and understand in case you run into a bug like this.